# Getting HTTP 404 when using Requests and EdgeGrid

Tags: python, api, http, cdn, akamai

please help.

I need to create monitoring the value of http errors in CDN akamai.
How i can do this using API?

```
import requests
from akamai.edgegrid import EdgeGridAuth
from urlparse import urljoin
baseurl = 'baseurl'
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = EdgeGridAuth(
client_token='client_token',
client_secret='client_secret',
access_token='access_token
)
result = s.get(urljoin(baseurl, '/media-reports/v1/download-delivery/19')) # 19 - ID 200 http requests
result.json()
```

From this code i get 404 status code...

So questions : 1) why i have 404 response? :)
2) Take i needed baseurl? or need something else?

Thanks all.

Comment: What is the real value of `baseurl`? What is the result of the `urljoin()`? (try printing it).

Comment: baseurl - this is personal url for api akamai

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this is to turn on debugging at the HTTP level.  This will show you exactly what's being sent and returned.  You can do this with the following code:

```
        import httplib as http_client
        http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
        logging.basicConfig()
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
        requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        requests_log.propagate = True
```